# remove css3 transition on mouseleave

Tags: html, css

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2vLjU/961/

```
#slide {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
    transition: 0.5s;
        opacity:0;
}
```

I want the fade and slide effect on mouseenter but not on mouseleave, because I think it's too much, how to do one-way only css3 transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the `transition` to the `:hover`. Then it will only happen on the hover state.

```
.wrapper:hover #slide {
    right: 0;
    opacity:1;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vLjU/962/)

Comment: but I rarely seen a transition is within :hover. Now I'm confused how to use them lol

Comment: That is true. But putting it on the `:hover` is a more [specific css selector](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) than the element alone. It's as if you had that as an additional class and you added it with javascript on mouseenter and removed it on mouseleave.